IDE Throws IOException when trying to rename a folder
IntelliJ throws a JavaIOException when trying to refactor -> rename a folder.
Since renaming it works if IntelliJ is closed, it seem that the IDE itself is holding a lock on the file.
This was not tracked in VCS (git).
How do I fix this behavior?

This is likely caused by a plugin running a process that keeps a lock on the file. For example this issue in JetBrains' issue tracker has GitHub copilot  as the culprit. It could even be one of the official plugins/services, as evidenced here.
Apart from the workaround you already suggested, I think the only solution is to disable the offending plugin/feature. You would have to do some digging yourself to find out which one(s) you have to disable, as that is impossible to tell from the information you have currently provided.

To workaround this issue I used git mv (Documentation) from the command line.
